# How to recreate these effects I found on IG?

Tags: video-editor

It is some kind of body glow, either blue or red with big 'chiaroscuro', everything else being black

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGg7S.jpg

that'd be mega helpful for me, you'd make my day :))

Answer (score 1):

You need a video editor that let you add curves to your video. Davinci Resolve is a great option.

1. Convert it to grayscale, you can simply reduce the saturation to 0.
2. Invert the curve. Augment the contrast making the curve more vertical.

[image]

3. Bring the green and Blue channels all the way down

[image]

Play a bit more. But that is the idea.

[image]

---

Option two for the final color is to add a color rectangle with different blending mode in the editor.

[image]

<sub>https://pixabay.com/es/photos/verano-flor-cabello-retrato-cara-4246927/</sub>